# Solving Boolean Expression (A' B' C')+(A' B' C)+(A' B C')+(A' B C)+(A B' C')+(A B' C)+(A B C')

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I have this boolean Expression. But I'm stuck in this last step (i.e --> **A'+AB'+ABC'**).

I know, it has to be simplified further, but I have no idea to gor further. Below is the simplified boolean expression that I could do...

Boolean Expression:

**Q = (A' B' C')+(A' B' C)+(A' B C')+(A' B C)+(A B' C')+(A B' C)+(A B C')**

**= A'B'(C+C')+A'B(C'+C)+AB'(C'+C)+ABC'**

**= A'B'(C+C')+A'B(C'+C)+AB'(C'+C)+ABC'**

**= A'B'+A'B+AB'+ABC'**

**= A'(B'+B)+A(B'+BC')**

**= A'+AB'+ABC'**

**= .....................**

**= .....................**

**= .....................**

**= .....................**

From here I don't know how to simplify further... Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can replace AB' with AB' + AB'C' and optimize further.

Comment: For an expression like this with only 3 terms it might help to write out a table. Or use a Karnaugh map.

Comment: Look up [Karnaugh Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). This is really handy for reducing logical expressions.

Comment: Hint: which is the only one of the eight possible terms not there. The answer is "not" that missing term.

Comment: Hint: there are only 8 possible combinations of 8 inputs, and your expression has 7 terms.

Comment: @user2233709: I need to know the theory of doing that... (Conversion of AB' to AB' + AB'C')

Comment: @asandwhich: I know K map do the business. But I need to simplify this using normal Logic Theorems

Comment: @KingDuken: I know K map do the business. But I need to simplify this using normal Logical Theorems

Comment: @TomCarpenter: This is a SOP taken from a Truth table. This is all the functions I have collected respective to all the output 1. Can you help me with simplifying this?

Comment: @ThePhoton: This is a SOP taken from a Truth table. This is all the functions I have collected respective to all the output 1. Can you help me with simplifying this?

Comment: @JaanuB AB' = AB'(C+C') = AB'C+AB'C' = AB'C+AB'C'+AB'C' = AB'(C+C')+AB'C' = AB'+AB'C'

Comment: @user2233709: you missed the A' right?

Comment: I did not miss it, I showed you how you could optimize further. But this is your homework, not mine, so I’d rather let you finish yourself.

Comment: @JaanuB, if there's 7 terms that produce '1' at the output, how many terms produce '0'? How can you use that answer to simplify the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$\overline A+A\overline B = \overline A + \overline B\$ (Absorption)

Absorption justification (because of comments to another answer).  Expand the first term and then absorb it into second.

\$\overline A (1 + \overline B) +A\overline B\$ (Annulment)

\$\overline A + \overline A\ \overline B +A\overline B\$ (Distributive)

\$\overline A + \overline B (\overline A + A)\$ (Idempotent)

\$\overline A + \overline B\$

Comment: ROFL I voted for the other answers.  They are more complete.  Even the comments are helpful.  I clarified your confusion.  If you had duplicated other terms to reduce A B C' from the start, you would of not needed Absorption.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this function

\$A' + AB'\$

Since the first term is a single input the second term can be implied as...

\$A'\$ **or else** \$B'\$

so it is equivalent to

\$A' + B'\$

This is an [absorption law](https://www.electronics-micros.com/electronics/rules-of-boolean-algebra/).

So your term 
\$A'+AB'+ABC'\$ can be simplified to
\$A'+ (B'+BC')\$

Then you can do the same with \$B\$ and end up with

\$A'+ B'+ C'\$

Which is btw.

\$(ABC)'\$

**ADDITION:**

In an attempt to explain the absorption law, let me try to demonstrate it in code.

\$A' + AB'\$ can be expressed as

```
If Not A then
    Return True
ElseIf A AND Not B Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

However, the "A" part of the ElseIf is redundant since you would not get there if A were not true, so the code can be simplified to.

```
If Not A then
    Return True
ElseIf Not B Then <--- A must be true here
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

i.e. \$A' + B'\$

The A is implied and true in the second term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57277/discussion-on-answer-by-trevor-solving-boolean-expression-a-b-ca-b-c).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this very quickly if you notice that there are only 8 possible combinations of 3 inputs, and your expression has 7 terms. Therefore there is only one combination of inputs that produces a '0' output. By inspection, you can see this is the combination A = 1, B = 1, C = 1.

So you want a circuit that produces 0 when all 3 inputs are high, and 1 otherwise.

This is simply a 3-input NAND gate.

The corresponding logic expression is, like another answer already found,

$$(ABC)'.$$

Comment: very true, and how I would do it, but not sure that would get you a pass in an exam though :)

Comment: @Trevor, you'd have to dress it up with some guff about "we can find the solution to the inverse problem and then negate its output" or something.

Comment: YUp, or show it both ways for brownie points :) and to verify your answer.

Comment: How can you Suddenly take the answer like that?

Comment: @JaanuB, if you want to show your work in tedious detail, write down the truth table. Notice that there's only one row with a 0 output. Write an expression that gives 1 for that row and 0 everywhere else. Then put a NOT gate on the output of that logic.

Comment: Then recognize that NAND is actually a simpler gate than AND.

Comment: @ThePhoton: are you telling me to do this in Maxterms??

Comment: @JaanuB, I don't know. I never learned "minterms" and "maxterms".